# ReactJS router issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am working with Node JS

I made a little project which using ReactJS Routing and i am getting error without a clue how to track it.

Here is my code :

main.js ,

```
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router');
var routes = require('./routes');


ReactDOM.render(<Router>{routes}</Router>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

routes.js:

```
 "use strict";

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require ('react-router');

var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Route = Router.Route;

var routes = (
    <Route path="app" path="/" component={require('./components/app')} >
    <DefaultRoute component={require('./components/homePage')} />
    <Route path="authors" component={require('./components/authors/authorPage')} />
    <Route path="about" component={require('./components/about/aboutPage')} />
    </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

app.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Header = require('./common/header');
var reactRouter = require('react-router');
var RouteHandler = reactRouter.RouteHandler;

$= jQuery = require('jQuery');

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(<div>
            <Header/> 
            <div className="container-fluid">
            <RouteHandler/>
            </div>
        </div>);
    }

}

module.exports = App;
```

homePage.js :

```
"use strict";

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div className ="jumbotron">
            <h1>Pluralsight</h1>
            <p>React , react route, and flux for ultra-responsive web aps.</p>
            </div>);
  }
}

module.exports = Home;
```

Here is my folders order :

[image]

The errors i get is :

[image]

Comment: can you show code of homepage component ?

Comment: which version of react-router are you using ??

Comment: i added the homePaje . i am using version :  "react-router": "^4.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to write `module.exports = xxx` in one of the components that you have created. 
If you are using `export default xxx` in any of the files then while importing it you need to write `var xxx = require(path).default`

Comment: I checked all my file and i forgot nothing